# Multiselect options with each option selecting multiple times using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Select numbers (you can select each number any number of times):

```
 <select name="number_selection" method="post" id="number_selection" >
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1 </option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Select" id="select_button"/> 


 <div id="feedback"> </div>
```

what I've tried in jquery is this....

```
$('#select_button').click(function(){
    var gs= $('#number_selection').val();
    $('#feedback').html(gs);            
    });
```

Now, What i am trying to do is, if i select a number from the options, it should display in the 'div' and if i select another number or the same number again, it should display beside the first number, but i am only able to select only a single number, not multiple numbers. I want the do this using jquery

If you don't understand my problem, i can explain you further. Please help.

And also if I want to deselect each element from the list appended?
I've tried this... but isn't working.

```
$('#select_button').click(function(){
    var gs= $('#number_selection').val();
    $('#feedback').append(gs + '  ' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" id="gs_remove" />' + '<br>');

    });

    $('#gs_remove').click(function(){
    (this).hide();
    });
```

but with this i am not able to remove each selected option.

Comment: What the Select button purpose?? And you want to display data in feedback div??

Comment: every time you are replacing the #fcb_pt_gs html. You could put the other number below by writing `$('#fcb_pt_gs').append(gs);`, or if you want something like "12345..." you can do this: `$('#fcb_pt_gs').html($('#fcb_pt_gs').html() + gs);`

Comment: And also if I want to deselect each element from the list appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```js
 $('#fcb_pt_gs').html(gs);
```

by

```js
 $('#fcb_pt_gs').append(gs);
```

Comment: and what if I want to deselect each number ?

Comment: ('#select_button').click(function(){
    var gs= $('#number_selection').val();
    $('#feedback').append(gs + '  ' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" id="gs_remove" />' + '<br>');

    });

    $('#gs_remove').click(function(){
    (this).hide();
    });              but with this i am not able to remove each selected option.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select_button').click(function() {
    var _val = $('#fcb_pt_gs').text();
    var gs= $('#number_selection').val();

    if( _val == "" ) {
      var _collection = [];
    }
    else {
      // Add in collection
      var _collection = [_val];
    }

    _collection.push( gs );

    $('#fcb_pt_gs').html( _collection.join(',') );           
});
```